# how do i do vector multiplication in batch with python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

for example, I have a vector of shape[1,D]

if D = 4

```
v = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]]) # shape = [1,4]
```

and do

```
np.dot(v.T,v)
```

the result will be

```
Out[80]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16]])
```

now I have lots of vectors, and they are in the shape of [N,D]

that's N vectors with D dimensions

How can I get the result in the most efficient way

PS: the result would be a numpy.ndarray of shape [N,D,D]

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output of  `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]` will be?

Comment: array([[[1, 2], [2, 4]],[[4, 2],[2, 1]]])

Comment: `np.einsum` and `np.matmul` can handle this.  Actually this is the outer product so you you don't need those.  Broadcasting can handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [758]: v = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
In [759]: v2 = np.vstack([v,v])
In [760]: v2.shape
Out[760]: (2, 4)
In [761]: v2[:,None,:]*v2[:,:,None]
Out[761]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
        [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
        [ 4,  8, 12, 16]],

       [[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
        [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
        [ 4,  8, 12, 16]]])
In [762]: _.shape
Out[762]: (2, 4, 4)
```

I'm using broadcasting to construct an outer product.

Checking against your comment example

```
In [763]: x2= np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
In [764]: x2[:,None,:]*x2[:,:,None]
Out[764]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 4]]])
```

You wanted:

```
In [765]: np.array([[[1, 2], [2, 4]],[[4, 2],[2, 1]]])
Out[765]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 4]],

       [[4, 2],
        [2, 1]]])
```

the numbers are there, but 2nd plane is flipped.  Is that really what you want?  Evidently there's some ambiguity in how the dimensions map.  If this is really what you want, explain how you'd do it iteratively.

---

With `einsum` this outer product is

```
In [770]: np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', x2,x2)
Out[770]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 4]]])
```

With `matmul` the expression is: `v2[:,:,None]@v2[:,None,:]`.

Comment: Thanks bro, that's exactly what I need.